# ADF V2 Self-hosted IR LinkedService status

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-factory

In Azure ADF V1, the gui allowed us to see that the data gateway was online and would tell us if an on-prem linked service was unavailable. I haven't found the powershell cmdlet that would give me the same information. 
My current problem is that a pipeline in ADF V2 is returning a "Cannot connect to SQL Server" error. I've run diagnostics in the self-hosted IR on the data gateway and can connect to the server. 
Does anyone have a script or suggestion to test the linkedService besides running the pipeline to see if it fails?
Thank you.
mf

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that there can be only one self-hosted IR per data factory and I was trying to add the V2 IR on the same VM that is already registered with a V1 data factory.